# Facebook comments API on Tumblr

Tags: html, facebook, api, tumblr

At the moment, I am trying to place facebook comments on my tumblr posts. I have managed to do so.

However, whenever I make a new post, it shares comments with the previous post. I think this has something to do with the URL being the same for each post, but I am not sure.

How can I use Facebook comments on Tumblr posts to be unique to each post?

Comment: This will be pretty hard to solve without any code or concrete examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the permalink for the data-href and not your blog's main URL.

Example:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{Permalink}" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>
```

Comment: A downvote for providing perfectly useful information, awesome.